# How to get rid of this message form the alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have an alert which appears to state that data has been submitted. Problem is thought that when the alert appears it comes up with this dialogue in the alert "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues" or something like that.

How can I get rid of this from the alert? If I can't get rid of it then is there are way I can get something like a prompt box or a confirmation box which only has an 'OK' button to appear because I don't want like the "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues" message.

Below is my code:

```
        function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        alert("Your Details for this Session has been submitted");
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop this from happening. Good browsers provide the option to prevent scripts from spawning alerts because alerts are often annoying. If this option could be revoked by the script, what has been gained?

Comment: But how come all my other alerts do not come up with that message but only this alert contains this message?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get it for that alert and not for the other one is because this alert will be fired programmaticly at the difference to be initiated by the user action.

open firebug

```
alert('hello')
```

Everytime this alert is called it show a conventional alert without the checkbox

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    alert('hello')
}, 500)
```

The first alert is normal the second one got the checkbox and allow you to prevent future alert because as steve says "good" browser can kind of understand something and have built in "supposedly helper"

Steve is right when he says that the message can not be removed but you can only control how the alert is open.

Perso I will not recommend you to use native alert because while the alert is open all the code on the page remain halted meaning nothing happen behind the popup. This can be annoying depending on your app.